# If port 443 is open does this definitely means taht the remote host has a certificate?

Tags: public-key-encryption, network-security

I know that if port 443 is open that means the remote host supports the secure protocol https that encrypts the traffic, and therefore, the remote host has private and public key pairs.

But my question is: If I knew that port 443 for a remote host is open, does this definitely means the remote host has a certificate ? Is it possible that there is a remote host which has private/public key pairs without certificate at all ??

Comment: I run my home ssh server on port 443 so that I can connect to it through work's firewall.  It has a certificate, but not the kind you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can run whatever I want on port 443. I can run on it also http (withous 's').

So, the answer is no! It doesn't means that that host has a certificate. Not even a public/private key system.

Comment: If you could provide example for a website that has port 443 open & no certificate, I will be thankful.

Comment: I didn't say that people are using it without certificate. I'm quite sure that "almost all" server out there will have https on that port and so they have apache configured with a certificate (and I can't provide a counter example and I have it with https on my server, too). But this doesn't mean that you must have https on port 443. If you want to successfully run https, you'll need to configure a certificate, but you can really run whatever you want on that port.